# How to read and write table with extra information as a dataframe and adding new columns from the informations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a file-like object generated from StringIO which is a table with lines of information ahead the table (see below starting from #TIMESTAMP).

I want to add extra columns to the exisiting table using the information "Date", "UTCoffset - Time (Substraction)" from #Timestamp and "ZenAngle" from #GLOBAL_SUMMARY.

I used pd.read_csv command to read it but it only worked when I skip the first 8 rows which includes the information I need. Also the Error "TypeError: data argument can't be an iterator" was reported as I tried to import the object below as dataframe.

```
#TIMESTAMP
UTCOffset,Date,Time
+00:30:32,2011-09-05,08:32:21

#GLOBAL_SUMMARY
Time,IntACGIH,IntCIE,ZenAngle,MuValue,AzimAngle,Flag,TempC,O3,Err_O3,SO2,Err_SO2,F324
08:32:21,7.3576,52.758,59.109,1.929,114.427,000000,24,291,1,,,91.9

#GLOBAL
Wavelength,S-Irradiance,Time
290.0,0.000e+00
290.5,0.000e+00
291.0,4.380e-06
291.5,2.234e-05
292.0,2.102e-05
292.5,2.204e-05
293.0,2.453e-05
293.5,2.256e-05
294.0,3.088e-05
294.5,4.676e-05
295.0,3.384e-05
295.5,3.582e-05
296.0,4.298e-05
296.5,3.774e-05
297.0,4.779e-05
297.5,7.399e-05
298.0,9.214e-05
298.5,1.080e-04
299.0,2.143e-04
299.5,3.180e-04
300.0,3.337e-04
300.5,4.990e-04
301.0,8.688e-04
301.5,1.210e-03
302.0,1.133e-03
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can first use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) to create 3 `DataFrames`:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""#TIMESTAMP
UTCOffset,Date,Time
+00:30:32,2011-09-05,08:32:21

#GLOBAL_SUMMARY
Time,IntACGIH,IntCIE,ZenAngle,MuValue,AzimAngle,Flag,TempC,O3,Err_O3,SO2,Err_SO2,F324
08:32:21,7.3576,52.758,59.109,1.929,114.427,000000,24,291,1,,,91.9

#GLOBAL
Wavelength,S-Irradiance,Time
290.0,0.000e+00
290.5,0.000e+00
291.0,4.380e-06
291.5,2.234e-05
292.0,2.102e-05
292.5,2.204e-05
293.0,2.453e-05
293.5,2.256e-05
294.0,3.088e-05
294.5,4.676e-05
295.0,3.384e-05
295.5,3.582e-05
296.0,4.298e-05
296.5,3.774e-05
297.0,4.779e-05
297.5,7.399e-05
298.0,9.214e-05
298.5,1.080e-04
299.0,2.143e-04
299.5,3.180e-04
300.0,3.337e-04
300.5,4.990e-04
301.0,8.688e-04
301.5,1.210e-03
302.0,1.133e-03
"""
```

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp),
                 skiprows=9)

print (df1)
    Wavelength  S-Irradiance  Time
0        290.0      0.000000   NaN
1        290.5      0.000000   NaN
2        291.0      0.000004   NaN
3        291.5      0.000022   NaN
4        292.0      0.000021   NaN
5        292.5      0.000022   NaN
6        293.0      0.000025   NaN
7        293.5      0.000023   NaN
8        294.0      0.000031   NaN
9        294.5      0.000047   NaN
10       295.0      0.000034   NaN
11       295.5      0.000036   NaN
12       296.0      0.000043   NaN
13       296.5      0.000038   NaN
14       297.0      0.000048   NaN
15       297.5      0.000074   NaN
16       298.0      0.000092   NaN
17       298.5      0.000108   NaN
18       299.0      0.000214   NaN
19       299.5      0.000318   NaN
20       300.0      0.000334   NaN
21       300.5      0.000499   NaN
22       301.0      0.000869   NaN
23       301.5      0.001210   NaN
24       302.0      0.001133   NaN
```

```
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp),
                  skiprows=1,
                  nrows=1)

print (df2)
   UTCOffset        Date      Time
0  +00:30:32  2011-09-05  08:32:21

df3 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp),
                  skiprows=5,
                  nrows=1)

print (df3)
       Time  IntACGIH  IntCIE  ZenAngle  MuValue  AzimAngle  Flag  TempC   O3  \
0  08:32:21    7.3576  52.758    59.109    1.929    114.427     0     24  291   

   Err_O3  SO2  Err_SO2  F324  
0       1  NaN      NaN  91.9
```

Comment: I add first steps of solution, buit it is not clear for me, how are joined columns from `df2` and `df3` to `df1`. Can you explain more? Also 3. column of `df1` is missing, is it correct?